# Publishing Private App on Google Play Store/Android

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, private, mobile-application

Our team will create a private android app for the users of different countries/organizations. I didn't understand the google docs about it. I have a developer account but they say if you want to publish a private app you need to add all organizations ID to your app. How can I reach all of them IDs? Is there a easy solution for my situation like creating an app privately and distributing with some special link for android users that I will share with different organizations.

([https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139#zippy=%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization:~:text=For%20each%20organization%20that%20you%20want%20to%20publish%20the%20app%20to%2C%20enter%20the%20Organization%20ID%20and%20a%20description%20(or%20name)%20and%20click%20Add.%C2%A0You%20can%20enter%20up%20to%201000%C2%A0organizations%C2%A0per%20app.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139#zippy=%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization:%7E:text=For%20each%20organization%20that%20you%20want%20to%20publish%20the%20app%20to%2C%20enter%20the%20Organization%20ID%20and%20a%20description%20(or%20name)%20and%20click%20Add.%C2%A0You%20can%20enter%20up%20to%201000%C2%A0organizations%C2%A0per%20app.))

Is there any better solution or some brief clarification about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

for the organizations part,check out https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/7042126?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-managed-google-play-accounts-enterprise%2Cadministrator-account ,if you just want to share some special link with different organizations,check out [internal app sharing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/)